# How to pack function and its argument to keep code clean and simple

Tags: python, multithreading, queue

The working code posted below uses Python `threading` and `queue` module to initiate a single `MyThread` thread which grabs an incoming data via global `queue` object (a list of dictionaries). Each data dictionary is designed to store the function to be run by `MyThread`. The `data` dictionary's `function` key is expected to be used to pass the function to run. And its `function_argument` key is to be used to pass the function's argument.

Instead of using the dictionary `function` and `function_argument` keys I would rater "pack" the function and its argument into a single variable or an object to pass it along to `MyThread`? So `MyThread` would simply grab the function and its arguments and simply run it with any extra work of unpacking the data dictionary.

Sure, I could simply define the executable command as string:

```
cmd = "myFunction(argument = 'Somewhere over the rainbow')"
eval(cmd)
```

But that seems to be an ugly solution.

```
import logging
formatter = logging.Formatter("[%(levelname)s] %(asctime)s, %(message)s", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
handler = logging.StreamHandler()
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
log.addHandler(handler)
log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

from threading import Thread
import Queue as Queue
global queue
queue = Queue.Queue()


class MyThread(Thread):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        Thread.__init__(self, parent)

    def run(self):
        global queue
        while True:
            data = queue.get()

            function = data.get('function')
            argument = data.get('function_argument')

            output = function(argument)

            queue.task_done()
            log.info('MyThread: Task completed. Exiting.')
            exit()


threads = []
thread = MyThread()
threads.append(thread)
thread.start()


def myFunction(argument):
    log.debug('Running myFunction using argument: %r' % argument)

argument = 'Somewhere over the rainbow'
data = {'function': myFunction, 'function_argument': argument}
queue.put(data)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just put a `lambda` (or `functools.partial)` function in your queue:

```
data = lambda : myFunction(argument)
```

or

```
import functools
data = functools.partial(myFunction,argument)
```

then:

```
queue.put(data)
```

then use as is:

```
data = queue.get()
output = data()
```

Comment: Thanks for showin the solution on how to use `lambda`. If possible please post another example on how to use `functors.partial` too!